# Как узнать о текущем положении телефона?

Tags: android, c++, gps

Как узнать о текущем положении телефона?

Comment: принципиально c++?

Comment: К сожаления, да..с java не знаком,а времени нет..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работа с gps в Qt, смотрите по ссылке ниже:

http://2lx.ru/2014/06/rabota-s-gps-v-qt/

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).